# Change Screen Programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

What is the simplest way to change the screen to another view controller with Swift 3? I looked online and only saw methods for Swift 1 and 2.

Comment: You can use the Swift1/2 version, then go to Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax

Answer (score 1):

It should be similar in Swift 3 vs. 2. Usually if you type in the Swift 2 code into Xcode 8, it will give you the changes for the new Swift or will give you an error which could tell you what to change

Try this as an example:

```
let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("billInfo") as! BillInfoViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Ok. What do you think the easiest way to do this is? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment. Please do not post comments as answers.